# Trying to filter multiple keywords in same objects, using angular and checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter

This is my first question so please bear with my newbness.

I am trying to filter an array of objects by keywords using checkbox inputs.
I want only the objects that contain all the keywords selected to show.

When each object only had 1 keyword it worked perfect, but now that each object has multiple keywords, I have been struggling to get it to work.

I have been trying to use this as a reference: http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/

I have tried many variations but this is the closest I get.

This current version is my latest attempt to use a for loop to cycle through the array, but now it doesn't really filter at all, but just toggles everything at once..

```js
var app = angular.module("Grou", []);

app.controller('GrouCntrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.title = 'download this awesome stuff!';
  $scope.promo = 'this is the description text';
  $scope.products =

    [{
        name: 'Bill',
        keywords: ['standing', 'man', 'america'],
        image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
      },

      {
        name: 'Francois ',
        keywords: ['man', 'sitting', 'europe'],
        image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
      },

      {
        name: 'jack ',
        keywords: ['sitting'],
        image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
      },

      {
        name: 'jack ',
        keywords: ['walking', 'woman'],
        image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
      },

      {
        name: 'jack ',
        keywords: ['lying down', 'europe'],
        image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
      },

      {
        name: 'jack ',
        keywords: ['sitting', 'america'],
        image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
      },
    ];

  $scope.keywordsIncludes = [];


  $scope.includesKeywords = function(keywords) {
    var i = $.inArray(keywords, $scope.keywordsIncludes);
    if (i > -1) {
      $scope.keywordsIncludes.splice(i, 1);
    } else {
      $scope.keywordsIncludes.push(keywords);
    }
  }

  $scope.keywordsFilter = function(products) {
    if ($scope.keywordsIncludes.length > 0) {

      var arrayLength = $.inArray(products.keywords).length;

      for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(products.keywords[i], $scope.keywordsIncludes) < 0)
          return;
      }

      return products;
    }
  }

  $scope.query = "";

  $scope.search = function(product) {
    if ($scope.query.length <= 0) return true;
    var query =
      ("" + $scope.query).toLowerCase(),
      fullName = [product.keywords].join(" ").toLowerCase();
    return fullName.indexOf(query) > -1;
  }

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,600,700|Dekko' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">


</head>

<body ng-app="Grou">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-box">
      <div class="leftcontainer">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <div class="container">
        <button>a propos</button>
        <button>accueil</button>
        <button>pack</button>
        <button>donation</button>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
      <div class="container">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="spacer">
  </div>

  <div class="bottomContainer">
    <div ng-controller="GrouCntrl">

      <div class="left-bar">
        <div class="leftcontainer">
          <br>
          <br>
          <input id="search-input" name="search" type="text" placeholder="chercher" ng-model="query">
          <br>
          <h4>Position</H4>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('standing')" />standing
          </br/>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('sitting')" />sitting
          </br/>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('walking')" />walking
          </br/>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('lying down')" />lying down
          </br/>


          <br>
          <h4>Another sub-header</h4>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('man')" />man
          </br/>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('woman')" />woman
          </br/>
          <br>
          <h4>Another sub-header</h4>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('america')" />america
          </br/>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('europe')" />europe
          </br/>


        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="right-bar">
        <div class="main">
          <div class="container">
            <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
            <h2> {{ promo }} </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="productBox">
            <div>
              <div class="container">
              </div>
              <div>
                <div ng-repeat="product in products  | filter:keywordsFilter| filter:search" class="thumbnail-container">
                  <div>
                    <img ng-src="{{product.image}}" class="thumbnails">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- Controllers -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance and feedback in my post appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OK i figured it out!

I was trying to pass the whole array and not the string.

I relooked at this reference to rework my filter: http://jsfiddle.net/6mqbm/

```js
var app = angular.module("Grou",[]);
app.controller('GrouCntrl',function($scope){

  $scope.title = 'download this awesome stuff!';
  $scope.promo = 'this is the description text';
  $scope.products =

 [
    { 
     name: 'Bill',
     keywords: ['standing', 'man', 'america'],
     image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
   },

    { 
     name: 'Francois ',
     keywords: ['man', 'sitting', 'europe'],
     image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
    },
    
    { 
     name: 'jack ',
     keywords: ['sitting'],
     image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
    },

    {
     name: 'jack ',
     keywords: ['walking', 'woman'],
     image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
    },

    {
     name: 'jack ',
     keywords: ['lying down','europe'],
     image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
    },

    {
       name: 'jack ',
     keywords: ['sitting', 'america'],
     image: 'img/thumbnails/Bill.png'
    },
];

    $scope.keywordsIncludes = [];


    $scope.includesKeywords = function(keywords) {
        var i = $.inArray(keywords, $scope.keywordsIncludes);
        if (i > -1) {
            $scope.keywordsIncludes.splice(i, 1);
        } 
        else {
            $scope.keywordsIncludes.push(keywords);
        }
    }
    
    $scope.keywordsFilter = function(products) {
        if ($scope.keywordsIncludes.length > 0) {            
               
                var arrayLength = $.inArray(products.keywords).length;

                for (var i in products.keywords) {
                    if ($scope.keywordsIncludes.indexOf(products.keywords[i]) != -1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        
        return false;
        }
    }

    $scope.query = "";

    $scope.search = function(product) {
        if ($scope.query.length <= 0) return true;
        var query = 
        (""+$scope.query).toLowerCase(),
        fullName = [product.keywords].join(" ").toLowerCase();
        return fullName.indexOf(query) > -1;
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,900,600,700|Dekko' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

      
    </head>

    <body ng-app="Grou">

        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo-box">
                <div class="leftcontainer">
    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-bar">
                <div class="container">
                    <button>a propos</button>
                    <button>accueil</button>
                    <button>pack</button>
                    <button>donation</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-box">
                <div class="container">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="spacer">
    </div>

    <div class="bottomContainer">
        <div ng-controller="GrouCntrl">

            <div class="left-bar">
                <div class="leftcontainer">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input id="search-input" name="search" type="text" placeholder="chercher" ng-model="query">
                    <br>
                    <h4>Position</H4>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('standing')"/> standing</br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('sitting')"/> sitting</br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('walking')"/> walking</br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('lying down')"/> lying down</br/>


                    <br>
                    <h4>Another sub-header</h4>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('man')"/> man</br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('woman')"/> woman</br/>
                    <br>
                    <h4>Another sub-header</h4>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('america')"/> america</br/>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-click="includesKeywords('europe')"/> europe</br/>


                </div>
            </div>    

            <div class="right-bar">
                <div class="main" >
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1> {{ title }} </h1>
                        <h2> {{ promo }} </h2>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="productBox">
                        <div>
                            <div class="container">
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div ng-repeat="product in products  | filter:keywordsFilter| filter:search" class="thumbnail-container" >
                                    <div>
                                      <img ng-src="{{product.image}}" class="thumbnails">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    

    <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>

        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```